# On resizing the window size the various texts and images overlap

Tags: html, css, overlapping

I have a website, I am facing an issue. On making the window size smaller the various contents of my page overlap.

The smaller the size goes, the more overlap is seen.

[Here is my website](http://www.saimotorsandac.com) if you want to check my problem.

Comment: Please include the essence of your problem in the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used to this

```
body{min-width:1250px;} // according to your website
```

define `min-width` on your `body`

**if your main** `div` `width is 1200px` than define your `body {min-width:1200px;}`

Comment: @Mr.Alien I m checking and now apply this solution on firebug than give OP how to say that this is bed solution ...

Comment: But having such a huge width is wrong, instead learn CSS positionings so this will never happen

Comment: @Mr.Alien now resize OP website and scroll  left to right now check to problum

Comment: @Mr.Alien That's just _plainly_ and _patently_ wrong - fixed-width websites are unfortunately still the norm.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Edited to clarify. And I failed to mention also entirely feasible in a great many cases. Dynamism on pages is something I strive for, surely, I'm not against this, but to assert that to do otherwise is _wrong_ is, well, _wrong_.

Comment: @GrantThomas this is the wrong way to solve this particular issue as it was just because of lack of positioning knowledge, fixed width websites are good, but beginners often fall in trouble while using floats which they don't clear, responsive are far beyond, shouldn't go for responsive unless and until your basics are clear, but for this, the solution is not correct :)